# Map mysql Json field to Entity column in spring data jpa

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a field, metadata in a given entity. I need to keep the type of this field as json in mysql. I am facing trouble mapping this column to entity attribute. I've kept the data type to String in java DTO. But the problem is while creating a resource using POST - I need to pass the escape characters before double quotes("). Please help me in getting rid of those escape characters. In response - I am able to remove them via @JsonRawProperty.

So far I've tried this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Sample")
public class Sample
{  
    @Column(name = "properties",columnDefinition = "json")
    @JsonRawProperty
    private String properties;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}

With this - this works but I need to pass the json as string with escape characters in post request like this :

{
    "name": "test",
    "properties": "{\"key\":\"value\"},
}
```